# Excel VBA - Stop converting date to number

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I've an Excel file (.xlsx) which contains cells with Dates like this: "14/12/2015".
The Dates are calculated with formulaes like this: "=D3+1".

Now I've got a little VBA script which does some things and saves the data to a .csv file... The issue is that all my dates are converted to normal numbers something like this: 41992

How can I stop excel from doing this? Anyone any ideas?

Cheers!
Patrick

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Dates in Excel are really just numbers. Use the FORMAT function in your code to convert back to string.

```
Format(nValue, "yyyy-mm-dd")
```

Comment: Sounds good, thanks! Is it possible to use this command for a column or do I have to loop every cell in my column?

Comment: you can apply the format to a data range in Excel. Doesn't have to be a cell by cell approach.

Comment: So if you were setting a range format and saving as a csv file, you could use something like: rSomeRange.NumberFormat = "yyyy-mm-dd" and do the save like: Someworkbook.SaveAs("c:\SomeFile.csv.", xlCSVMSDOS).

Answer (score -1):

No need to do it in VBA, You can do it directly in the cell where you have the formula D3+1

Just use    `=text(D3+1,"dd/mm/yyyy")`

Comment: OP is already using VBA; no need to complicate the sheet with cell-based solution.

Comment: There is a formula in the cell already... Why would you use vba when there is a function already :(